# Adding rows to Dataset in asp.net

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I am using following code to access data in my dataset (visually created) in asp.net

```
Dim ta As New tblArticlesTableAdapter()
Dim dt As dsArticles.tblArticlesDataTable = ta.GetData(txtArtNo.Text)
```

I want to add new rows to the tblArticles table.  How can I access it using above styled code?

I tried to do:

```
Dim drNewRow as datarow = DataSet1.tblTest.NewRow
drNewRow.item(1) = "User Added An Item"
DataSet1.tblTest.rows.add (drNewrow)
TableAdapter1.update (DataSet1.tblTest)
```

Comment: Its not clear (to me anyway) what you mean by "How can I access it using above styled code?" Access it how?

Comment: try this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: By accessing I mean adding, deleting and Editing records in database the way i have given the code example